# Serving map files with Nginx

Tags: maps, tilestache, nginx

Currently i am serving map tiles with gunicorn and tilestache with nginx reverse proxying gunicorn. This works, although for some reason i am unable to do anything with the appearance of the map as it keeps defaulting to this modest maps index. Currently i am using mbtiles for this setup however i would like to scrap gunicorn and tilestache and serve the .png files directly from nginx, but i currently have no idea how to go about doing that. I seek help in the configuration for this kind of setup. I have used mbutil to convert my mbtiles into a directory for the .png files.